# ASP.NET MVC Kendo UI Excel Grid Data for Filename

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a grid that can display all products, but we have buttons to decide what products to show in the grid, like "Caps", "Baseballs", or "Shoes".

When a button is selected, the Ajax call lets my jQuery handle the `onDataBound` event to filter the data correctly and Excel pulls all of the data and not just the number shown on the PageSize setting.

But, all reports are called "Report.xlsx", and I would like to customize them with the product, like "CapsReport.xlsx" or "BaseballsReport.xlsx".

How can I send this value to the `FileName("Report.xlsx")` below?

```
<script>
function onButtonClick() {
  $(this).addClass('active').sublings().removeClass('active');
  var value = $(this).val() + 'Report.xlsx'; // this is the value I want to send to the Excel Filename
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>().Excel.FileName(value)) // this line is obviously wrong
}
</script>

<div id="ReadTypeBtnGroup" class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" id="caps" value="Caps" class="btn btn-default">Caps</button>
    <button type="button" id="baseballs" value="Baseballs" class="btn btn-default">Baseballs</button>
    <button type="button" id="shoes" value="Shoes" class="btn btn-default">Shoes</button>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
    .AutoBind(false)
    .DataSource(o => o
        .Ajax()
        .Read(o2 => o2.Action("GetReport", "Report"))
        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(true)
    )
    .Events(o => o.DataBound("onDataBound"))
    .Excel(o => {
        o.AllPages(true);
        o.Collapsible(true);
        o.FileName("Report.xlsx");
    })
    .Name("grid")
    .Pageable()
    .ToolBar(o => {
        o.Excel();
    })
    )
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event handler to excelExport event like so `.Events(e => e.ExcelExport("excelExport"))`

There you can change the name of the file, among other properties.

For example:

```
function excelExport(e) {
    e.workbook.fileName = $("#someFieldHoldingFileName").val();
}
```

Comment: I was overriding the ExcelExport event, but I was writing to `e.fileName` instead of `e.workbook.fileName`. Thanks.